# Can I set the redirectUris for publicClient or spa from PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

When creating a new application in Azure from PowerShell using the command `New-AzureADApplication`, how can I set the redirect URIs if the application is a `spa` or `publicClient`, without using the Azure portal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using the Azure CLI (or other tool able to make rest requests) and making a `PATCH`-request to Microsoft Graph to update that specific part of the application manifest:

```
az rest `
    --method PATCH `
    --uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{id}' `
    --headers 'Content-Type=application/json' `
    --body "{spa:{redirectUris:['http://localhost:3000']}}"
```

[Microsoft Docs about az rest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az_rest)

Comment: Hmm, are you sure? It's not documented in the Graph docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/application?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: I see that there is no documentation for SPA but there is for publicClient:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http (and it worked for me)

Comment: This is where I found the info:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/9501#issuecomment-610979930 and tried it for SPA and it worked well.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70774430/add-redirecturis-for-azure-application-from-powershell