# Add redirectUris for Azure application from PowerShell

Tags: azure

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64258083/909180) describes how to set a redirectUri to an Azure application using the Azure CLI:

```
az rest `
    --method PATCH `
    --uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{id}' `
    --headers 'Content-Type=application/json' `
    --body "{spa:{redirectUris:['http://localhost:3000']}}"
```

That request will **overwrite** the current list of redirect URIs. How can I add an item to the list instead?

Comment: Hello @Kristoffer Jälén , Could you please try with Powershell cmd `Set-AzureADApplication` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0 .

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT I believe it won't be possible because I will have to first get the value, and then save the value, which will [lead to race conditions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/20875).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fetch the current values with `--method get`, convert it to an ArrayList and then add your new value:

```
$appdata = az rest --method get --uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{id}' | ConvertFrom-Json
$uris = [System.Collections.ArrayList]$appdata.web.redirectUris
$uris.Add('abc')
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use this below `Powershell script` to do the same using App Registration object id, client id and secrets .

```
 $url = "http://localhost:4000"
     $objectId = "<objectid>"
     $clientId = "<clientID>"
     $tenantValue ="<tenantID>"
     $clientSecret ="<client secret value>"
     $serviceAccountEmail = "yourusername.onmicrosoft.com"
     $serviceAccountPassword = "your password"


$webServiceURL = $url
Write-Host "$webServiceURL"
Write-Host "Done creating the webServiceURL"

Write-Host "Convert password to Secure string"
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $serviceAccountPassword -AsPlainText -Force
Write-Host "Done converting password to Secure string"

$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($serviceAccountEmail, $SecurePassword)

Write-Host "Logging in"
Login-AzAccount -Credential $Credential

$tid = (Get-AzTenant).Id

Write-Host "Getting token"
$tokenBody = @{
    'tenant' = $tid
    'client_id' = $clientId
    'scope' = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
    'client_secret' = $clientSecret
    'grant_type' = 'client_credentials'
}

$Params = @{
    'Uri' = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tid/oauth2/v2.0/token"
    'Method' = 'Post'
    'Body' = $tokenBody
    'ContentType' = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

$AuthResponse = Invoke-RestMethod @Params

$AuthResponse


$header = @{
    'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
    'Authorization' = "Bearer $($AuthResponse.access_token)"
}

$header

$redirectUris = (Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/$objectId" -Headers $header).spa.redirectUris

if ($redirectUris -notcontains "$webServiceURL") {
    $redirectUris += "$webServiceURL"
    Write-Host "Adding $webServiceURL to redirect URIs";
}


$body = @{
    'spa' = @{
        'redirectUris' = $redirectUris
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Patch -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/$objectId" -Headers $header -Body $body
```

***Here is the OUTPUT for Reference:-***
[image]

[image]